# Extending an objc unit test class runs the superclass's tests again

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, ocunit, sentestingkit

I am writing Objective-C unit tests in Xcode. I would like to extend my base class so I can reuse my setUp/tearDown methods. I created a header and put the imports there, since Xcode defaults to making just an implementation file.

Extending the base class works fine, except that all of its test methods are run a second time (or n times, depending on number of children).

My question is if this is the appropriate practice, or should I try something like base classes with no test methods?

Comment: I'd normally make separate test classes instead of putting the tests right inside the classes. That makes it easier to separate what code should be in a production build, and cleanly separates testing concerns from functionality (ie inheritance is not a problem).

Comment: Running the same test more than once is a waste of time. I would create a "base" class that only implements the setUp and tearDown methods.

Comment: Joachim, sorry if I wasn't clear, the tests are not in the class under test (you make a good point about keeping production code separate). Thanks Matthias, I may go that route, but it seems odd to me (coming from a more jUnit background, I don't think it happens that way there).